# <kbd> doesn't work in comments to answers/questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown

Adding `<kbd>` tags into comments on questions & answers doesn't work. It just displays the HTML.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

Comment: <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comments don't support HTML, merely a small subset of Markdown. See: https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting (you'll find this by clicking the "help" link under the big Add Comment button).

Comment: maybe it should be added. I've run into this limitation a few times when trying to deconstruct a question to help answer it.

Comment: Comments are pretty light-weight; adding HTML support (or rather, proper HTML sanitizing) probably won't happen. I suggest you go with some other sort of formatting or convention to indicate keystrokes - for instance, [Ctrl]+[F5], `Ctrl`+`F5`.

Comment: That's a much better solution than **`CTRL`** that I was doing.